# How do I fill out my FAFSA form if my mom has two jobs?

Tags: united-states, taxes, student-loan, fafsa

My mom gets two separate W-2 forms from two separate jobs. How do I take this into account when filling out my FAFSA form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They want to know how much your parents make. Just add all two W-2 forms together.